# Migrating Polymer project .5 to 1.0 error

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2012, polymer, nuget-package

I am trying to migrate my project from polymer .5 to polymer 1.0.

I have installed new version of polymer library, iron element & paper element.
But I am getting following error:

> polymer-micro.html:63 Uncaught TypeError: prototype.registerCallback is not a function

This page does not have any code like:

> Polymer('shape-menu',...

Also, I have noticed that directory structure remains same for core elements. It did not changed to iron/ neon elements.

So my code uses the same line to import htmls. Eg:

`<link rel="import" href="~/Scripts/Polymer/core-animated-pages/transitions/slide-from-right.html">`

Also Please check screen shot attached:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The directory structure maybe same but files present inside **are** different - refactored/split into multiple files. Since 0.5 and 1.0 are not compatible make sure you update your code too. The change is a big one and it is not simple as just updating your library.

Check their [migration guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html) on changes you would have to make. You may have to change quite a bit. Features that you use could be deprecated, so you will have to use newer alternative. The Polymer authors have created a tool called [polyup](http://polymerlabs.github.io/polyup/) to assist in migration, so check that out.